# Mysql Regexp Select By Number

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi guy i have a field in the database as json field

```
table some_table

field|   {"number":34,"name":"john"}
field|   {"number":60,"name":"mary"}
field|   {"number":44,"name":"mark"}
```

I want to make a query and select data where number > some value

```
select from some_table where field regexp (get_number) > 40
```

Is this possible?

---

I found this example to make a regexp select but only matching data

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '"key_name":"([^"]*)key_word([^"]*)"';
```

but i want to make a select inside a json where some number inside is bigger than...

thank you all for your future help.

Comment: Regex is not a good choice for checking number ranges.

Comment: normalise the db, stop storing data like this

Comment: You are really working your way into a corner. You should modify your database design so that you can query each piece of data.

Comment: Yeah. The beauty of json is that you can decode it

Comment: hi thank you. Im working in a place and this is the way they save the data for this specific field. I cant make changes to the database directly. This is the way they worked this field and they have a lot of records. I know that this way is not the recommended at all. Have you still have some ideas of how to do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to tell you that you cannot extract regex "captures" on mysql, you can only "match"

2nd, I want to tell you that the following query will only work if "number" is the first item

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,',',1),':',-1) > 40
```

This uses SUBSTRING_INDEX of mysql to get the string before the first "," 
which results to:
{"number":34

then get the string after the last ":" (which in this case, also the first)

that will result to:

34

edit:
Here's another version that will allow other order

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('{"number":34,"name":"john"}','"number":',-1),",",1) > 40
```

First call makes it: 34,"name":"john"}
Second call makes it: 34

SUBSTRING_INDEX:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the ability to load plugins on the MySQL database? If so, this might be exactly what you're looking for:

http://blog.kazuhooku.com/2011/09/mysqljson-mysql-udf-for-parsing-json.html

With the `mysql_json` UDF plugin compiled and installed, you would be able to run queries like this:

```
SELECT whatever_columns
  FROM some_table
  WHERE json_get(field, 'number') > 40
```

I haven't tried it yet, but would like to see if it works for you.

Comment: it worked with albertdiones aproach. but maybe this plugin could work too. ty